# Javascript for add cells in table

Tags: javascript, for-loop, cell

I have a problem. I need insert cell in a row. The content of cell is an element of an array. But is duplicate... Here my code:

```
function addFila() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');
    var table = iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("head_to_head h2h_home")[0];
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var fila = ["fecha", "liga", "equipolocal", "equipovisitante", "goleslocal", "golesvisitante"];

    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      row.insertCell(i);

      for (let x = 0; x <= fila.length; x++) {
        row.insertCell(i).innerHTML = fila[i];

       }    
    }   
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: can you better explain the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

row.insertCell() return new cell. If you want to create cell and use it you should save created cell in variable. You get duplicate because you call insertCell twice. I hope code below can help you

```js
var table = document.querySelector(".table");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var fila = ["fecha", "liga", "equipolocal", "equipovisitante", "goleslocal", "golesvisitante"];

for (let i = 0; i < fila.length; i++) {
  const insertedCell = row.insertCell(i);
  insertedCell.textContent = fila[i];
}
```

```css
table td {
border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell_1_1</td>
      <td>cell_1_2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell_2_1</td>
      <td>cell_2_2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```